# Organize Imports in Intellij on Commit but ignoring Namespaces

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, ide

How to disable Organize Imports in Intellij IDEA 13 for namespaces in xhtml/xml files? **Organize Imports on Commit** should organize our Java files ***but not*** our xhtml files.

Our problem are nested xhtml files together with RichFaces (and Omnifaces) functions. Intellij does not recognize namespaces in use (on that xhtml file they might not be) and removes it. However, the application won't work anymore.

- http://showcase-latest.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=functions&skin=ruby

Comment: Select src directory and `ctrl+alt+o` then ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An (not really sophisticated) solution is adding following comment in our xhtml file:

- `<!--suppress XmlUnusedNamespaceDeclaration -->`

See also:

- http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-126416